# Servidor DNS funciona en Servidor, no funciona en Cliente

Tags: ubuntu, dns

He montado un servidor DNS en un servidor, todo parece funcionar bien en el mismo servidor, pero no es asi en el cliente cuando pongo la IP del servidor DNS

-El firewall del servidor esta desactivado

Servidor:

```
user@server:/etc/bind# cat /etc/resolv.conf 
nameserver 127.0.0.1

user@server:/etc/bind# nslookup stackoverflow.com
Server:         127.0.0.1
Address:        127.0.0.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   stackoverflow.com
Address: 151.101.193.69
Name:   stackoverflow.com
Address: 151.101.129.69
Name:   stackoverflow.com
Address: 151.101.65.69
Name:   stackoverflow.com
Address: 151.101.1.69
```

Cliente:

```
user@cliente: cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 35.***.***.30

root@comocomer:~# nslookup stackoverflow.com
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

El cliente funciona perfectamente si cambio el servidor DNS:

```
user@cliente: nslookup stackoverflow.com
Server:         8.8.8.8
Address:        8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   stackoverflow.com
Address: 151.101.1.69
Name:   stackoverflow.com
Address: 151.101.65.69
Name:   stackoverflow.com
Address: 151.101.129.69
Name:   stackoverflow.com
Address: 151.101.193.69
```

Comment: verifica la dns configuradas en `/etc/network/interfaces`  en los nameservers cuales tiene y cambialos o dejalos en blanco para que tome directamente los de `/etc/resolv.conf` luego le das un restart a la interfas!

Comment: he probado, pero sigo en las mismas.

Answer (score 2):

Es necesario verificar que el servidor DNS esté escuchando en todas las interfaces y no solo en la loopback (127.0.0.1), esto se puede verificar con un:

```
netstat -nl | grep 53
```

Debe aparecer el puerto escuchando en la interfaz 0.0.0.0:53 o al menos en la IP que actualmente usa como servidor dns (35.***.***.30), de no ser así es necesario reconfigurar el servidor DNS para que escuche en todas las interfaces, por ejemplo en el caso de Bind se debe modificar el archivo

/etc/bind/named.conf.options

En la sección: options {

```
 listen-on { any; };
```

Luego se reinicia el servicio de bind

```
sudo service bind9 restart
```

Comment: con  listen-on { any; };
netstat -nl | grep 53
tcp        0      0 10.164.0.3:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:953           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
udp        0      0 10.164.0.3:53           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*

Sigo sin poder utilizarlo